# PHP range & foreach, use current value? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, database, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm currently coding a wordpress site.
I've been trying to solve this but i can't figure out what's going wrong !

So here is a simplified version of my problem :

### HTML

I have a list with select fields, each list item has a class :

```
<ul>
    <li class="class-1">
        <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="class-2">
        <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="class-3">
        <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Database

In my WP options database, i have several option values saved which I want to be automatically added to the right select field. Here is how the options are saved :

**option_name : option_value**

*For select 1 (class-1) :*

select_1_option_1 : Option 1 (1)

select_1_option_2 : Option 2 (1)

select_1_option_3 : Option 3 (1)

*For select 2 (class-2) :*

select_2_option_1 : Option 1 (2)

select_2_option_2 : Option 2 (2)

select_2_option_3 : Option 3 (2)

*etc...*

### PHP

So basically, now what i'm trying to do is to check the select field's class name, and query the options to fill the select field. Here is what i did :

```
function dynamic_options($form) {
    foreach($form['fields'] as &$field){
    //I call every single field on the form.
        $values = range(1, 10);
        // I create a range (1 to 10 so we can add up to 10 select fields) to use it in the loop.
        foreach($values as $v){
        // For each range value as $v : 1 then 2 then 3... to 10.
            $class = 'class-' . $v;
            if(strpos($field['cssClass'], $class) === false)
                continue;
            //Check if this field has class name 'class-' . $v. Using $v current value, so basically first call : class-1, second call : class-2...
            //If false, continue to the next field, if true :

            $rowname = 'select_' . $v . '_option_%';
            $prerowname = 'select_' . $v . '_option_';
            //Establish vars using the current $v value, example $rowname first call : select_1_option_%, second call : select_2_option_%.

            global $wpdb;
            $rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( " SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE '$rowname' " ));
            //Find row in database where option_name is like our var, first call : select_1_option_%, etc...

            if( $rows ){
                foreach( $rows as $row ) {
                    preg_match('([0-9]+)', substr($row->option_name,10), $matches);
                    //For each row, find the second number (I offset the first 10 positions, so we skip the first number and care only about the last one).
                    $name = $prerowname . $matches[0];
                    //Create the full option name using our previous established var and the match.
                    $optionname = get_option($name);
                    //Get the option value.

                    $choices[] = array('text' => $optionname);
                    $field['choices'] = $choices;
                    //Return the option value as a new select field option.
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
add_filter("gform_pre_render_1", "dynamic_options");
```

PS : Forget about the hook, i'm using Gravity Form so i hook my function before my form renders.

**So basically**

Everything from here is going so well, but now when i look at my select fields, the first on is ok, but the second and third one use the previous select fields options as well, and i don't get it ?

```
<ul>
    <li class="class-1">
        <select>
        <option value="Option 1 (1)"></option>
        <option value="Option 2 (1)"></option>
        <option value="Option 3 (1)"></option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="class-2">
        <select>
        <option value="Option 1 (1)"></option>
        <option value="Option 2 (1)"></option>
        <option value="Option 3 (1)"></option>
        <option value="Option 1 (2)"></option>
        <option value="Option 2 (2)"></option>
        <option value="Option 3 (2)"></option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="class-3">
        <select>
        <option value="Option 1 (1)"></option>
        <option value="Option 2 (1)"></option>
        <option value="Option 3 (1)"></option>
        <option value="Option 1 (2)"></option>
        <option value="Option 2 (2)"></option>
        <option value="Option 3 (2)"></option>
        <option value="Option 1 (3)"></option>
        <option value="Option 2 (3)"></option>
        <option value="Option 3 (3)"></option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can you help me guys with this, i would love my select fields to use only THEIR options, but i can't get what's making this happening ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but just try this:

```
  if( $rows ){
        $choices=array();
                foreach( $rows as $row ) {
                    preg_match('([0-9]+)', substr($row->option_name,10), $matches);
                    //For each row, find the second number (I offset the first 10 positions, so we skip the first number and care only about the last one).
                    $name = $prerowname . $matches[0];
                    //Create the full option name using our previous established var and the match.
                    $optionname = get_option($name);
                    //Get the option value.

                    $choices[] = array('text' => $optionname);
                    $field['choices'] = $choices;
                    //Return the option value as a new select field option.


           }
        }
```

Comment: I tried with $choices[0], now i have only one option for each select field only the last option, but no longer all options in each fields, so it's a good start !
The other $choices is not working.

Comment: WOW! It's working, you sir, made my day !

So fast, so good, nailed it ! 

Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

Get an array first that looks like this (using `mysql_query()` or PDO etc):

```php
array(4) {
  ["select_1_option_1"]=>
  string(12) "Option 1 (1)"
  ["select_1_option_2"]=>
  string(12) "Option 2 (1)"
  ["select_2_option_1"]=>
  string(12) "Option 1 (2)"
  ["select_2_option_2"]=>
  string(12) "Option 2 (2)"
}
```

Then,

```php
<?php
function optionParser(array $parseInput = array(), array $parsedOptions = array()) {
    if (empty($parseInput)) {
    return $parsedOptions;
  }

    $optionNames = array_keys($parseInput);

    $processedOption = $po = explode('_', $optionNames[0]);

    $parsedOptions[$po[1]][$po[3]] = $parseInput[$optionNames[0]];

    return optionParser(array_slice($parseInput, 1), $parsedOptions);
}

// assuming the array I asked for in the answer above is called $arrayFromMySQL
$arrayForHtml = optionParser($arrayFromMySQL);
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($arrayForHtml as $classKey => $optionSet) { ?>
        <li class="class-<?php echo $classKey;?>">
        <select>
            <?php foreach($optionSet as $option) {
                <option value="<?php echo $option;?>"></option>
            } ?>
        </select>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

PS: Welcome to StackOverflow, and nicely formatted question!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, i got what i wanted earlier.

And thanks for supporting and welcoming ;)

Comment: No problem! I mostly wrote the answer because I saw it as a recursive problem and wanted to see how long it would take to solve it that way ;)